# Changing the way PHP in_array does object comparison

Tags: php, object

I am working on using `in_array()` to check if a `Course` object called (appropriately named) `Course` is in an array.

One issue I am having is, I want to use a specific property within my `Course` object to do the object comparison, instead of comparison of the entire object.

Specifically, I want to use the `$course->getShortName()` to do the comparison. Why? Because all the other private variables within my `Course` object can be different, except for the `short_name` property which can stay the same, and that's why I want to use it to do the object property.

**Method that does the comparison**:

```
public function overlap($courses, $course_temp) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($courses); $i = $i + 1) {
        if ($this->overlapCourses($courses[$i], $course_temp)) {
            // Push the class that is conflicted to the conflictedClass
            // array
            // TODO: Figure out why it's being added to the list
            if(!in_array($courses[$i], $this->conflictClasses)) {
                array_push($this->conflictClasses, $courses[$i]);
            }

            // Push the class that is conflicted with to the
            // conflictedClass array
            // TODO: Figure out why it's being added to the list
            if(!in_array($course_temp, $this->conflictClasses)) {
                array_push($this->conflictClasses, $course_temp);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Getter from my `Course` class**

```
public function getShortName(){
    return $this->short_name;
}
```

`tl;dr`: Instead of compare object, compare one property of the object

Comment: You cannot change the behavior of in_array, but maybe this is helpful: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-uintersect.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see any existing function that would apply here.
You could use array_filter to perform what you want :

```
function object_in_array($needle, array $array, $method) {
    $propertyToMatch = $needle->$method();
    // the $matches var will contain all the objects that have the property matching your object property
    $matches = array_filter($array, function($object) use ($propertyToMatch, $method) {
        return $propertyToMatch === $object->$method();
    });

    // If there is at least 1 result, your object property is matching one of your array of objects
    return count($matches) > 0;
}
```

## Usage

```
if (object_in_array($myObject, $courses, 'getShortName')) {
    ....
}
```

Of course you should verify if the $method method exists and throw exceptions if not.

Comment: Thanks! What's the big O of array_filter?

Comment: sorry ? I do not understand your question